# Why is getElementsByTagName() not working for me?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

I am trying to get info from the [OMDb API](http://www.omdbapi.com/).  I found some code but it's not working right:

```
$loc = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='.$lookup_title.'&r=xml';
$dom = new DOMDocument();  
$dom->load($loc);  
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('movie') as $e) {

    $imdb = $e->getElementsByTagName('imdbID')->item(0)->textContent; 
    $year = $e->getElementsByTagName('year')->item(0)->textContent;  
    $plot = $e->getElementsByTagName('plot')->item(0)->textContent; 
    $poster = $e->getElementsByTagName('poster')->item(0)->textContent;   

}
```

The XML output from OMDb API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root response="True">
  <movie title="Terminator 2: Judgment Day"
         year="1991"
         rated="R"
         released="03 Jul 1991"
         runtime="137 min"
         genre="Action, Sci-Fi"
         director="James Cameron"
         writer="James Cameron, William Wisher Jr."
         actors="Arnold Schwarzenegger, Linda Hamilton, Edward Furlong, Robert Patrick"
         plot="Almost 10 years have passed since the first cyborg called The Terminator tried to kill Sarah Connor and her unborn son, John Connor. John Connor, the future leader of the human resistance, is now a healthy young boy. However another Terminator is sent back through time called the T-1000, which is more advanced and more powerful than its predecessor. The Mission: to kill John Connor when he's still a child. However, Sarah and John do not have to face this threat of a Terminator alone. Another Terminator is also sent back through time. The mission: to protect John and Sarah Connor at all costs. The battle for tomorrow has begun..."
         language="English, Spanish"
         country="USA, France"
         awards="Won 4 Oscars. Another 20 wins &amp; 21 nominations."
         poster="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg5NzUwMDU5NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjk2MDA4Mg@@._V1_SX300.jpg"
         metascore="68"
         imdbRating="8.5"
         imdbVotes="636,472"
         imdbID="tt0103064"
         type="movie"/>
</root>
```

**Error**:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `imdb`, `year`, `plot`, and `poster` parts are XML *attributes*, not *elements*, so use [DOMElement::getAttribute()](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) rather than `getElementsByTagName()`:

```
$imdb = $e->getAttribute('imdbID'); 
$year = $e->getAttribute('year');  
$plot = $e->getAttribute('plot'); 
$poster = $e->getAttribute('poster');
```